# Paste between Excel graphs without changing display ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Say I create a X-Y graph in Excel from one section of my data and set up the axis ranges as I need them to be. Then I create a second X-Y graph from a different section of the data. Now I want to overlay the new graph's contents into the first graph, so I select a point in the second graph and Copy. Then I select the first graph and Paste. The new data *is* added to the first graph, but the axis ranges change to new automatic defaults.

How I can quickly add one graph's data to another without changing anything else about the destination graph's layout? Something like the ability to paste data only, without formatting, in the spreadsheet.

Comment: If possible, please provide the sample data about create charts.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want. But I think if you provide specific axis min and max, then pasting in new data won't encourage Excel to compute a new default axis scale.